# C sockets HTTP request asynchronously printing response, when there is no explicit command to do so

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm trying to learn C sockets right now by making a simple web scraper, but doing the socket programming and HTTP requests myself, currently using socket libraries. I've written a function that successfully sends a non-SSL request to `http://mirror.vcu.edu` and stores the output in a variable called `response`.

```
char *noSSLRequest(REQUEST_HEADER_INFO *request_header_info) {
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    char *requestHeader;
    unsigned short serverPort;
    char serverIP[13];
    domainToIP(request_header_info->host, serverIP);
    char *response = calloc(0, 0);
    ssize_t bytesReceived = 0;


    int sockFD; //Only supporting IPV4 right now, returns file descriptor for socket

    if ((sockFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < -1) {
        freeRequestHeaderInfo(request_header_info);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not open socket in http.c getHTMLBody(). Reason for error %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "LOG: Socket file descriptor is %d" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, sockFD);
    serverPort = 80;
    memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton(serverIP, &serverAddress.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockFD, (const struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {
        freeRequestHeaderInfo(request_header_info);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not connect socket in http.c getHTMLBody(). Reason for error %s",
                strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "\nLOG: Connected socket at descriptor %d to IP %s and port %d" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, sockFD,
           serverIP, serverPort);

    requestHeader = craftRequestHeader(request_header_info);

    if (send(sockFD, requestHeader, strlen(requestHeader), 0) < 0) {
        freeRequestHeaderInfo(request_header_info);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not send request. Reason for error %s",
                strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "\nLOG: Sent HTTP request from socket at descriptor %d to IP %s and port %d." ANSI_COLOR_RESET,
           sockFD,
           serverIP, serverPort);


    free(requestHeader);
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "\nLOG: Starting receive operation" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
    ssize_t bytesReceivedPrevious = -1;
    char buffer[RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE];


    while (bytesReceived < (RESPONSE_MAX_LEN * sizeof(char)) && bytesReceived > bytesReceivedPrevious) {
        bytesReceivedPrevious = bytesReceived;
        bytesReceived = recv(sockFD, buffer, RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        response = realloc(response, sizeof(*response) + RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE);
        strcat(response, buffer); //Append to the end, safe because recv takes care of limiting buffer size
    }
    response = realloc(response, sizeof(*response) + sizeof(char));
    response[strlen(response)] = '\0';
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "\nLOG: Received HTTP response from socket at descriptor %d to IP %s and port %d.\n\n\n\n\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET,
           sockFD,
           serverIP, serverPort);
    if (close(sockFD) < 0) {
        freeRequestHeaderInfo(request_header_info);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not close socket in http.c getHTMLBody(). Reason for error %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "\nLOG: Closed socket at descriptor %d" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, sockFD);
    freeRequestHeaderInfo(request_header_info);

    return response;
}
```

Everything works fine, response has a null terminator and life is good, except that in my console, for some reason, I'm getting the output of `response` printed out. I feel like something is leaking somewhere, because this output is in green as well even though after every log I am resetting the color back to default. I know some of the flags and other stuff up there is not shown, I couldn't get all the info and code here so I have a [github repo](https://github.com/ytpillai/amazon-books-scraper) and more detailed [issue](https://github.com/ytpillai/amazon-books-scraper/issues/2).

Picture of log is on here and on the issue, though I couldn't get the full output so the non-coloured text version is on the issue.

[image: Image of function log output]

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
response = realloc(response, sizeof(response) + RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

and this code

```
response = realloc(response, sizeof(response) + sizeof(char));
```

both cause undefined behavior.

`response` is a `char *` - a pointer.  `sizeof()` a pointer is the **size of the pointer**, not the length of the string it points to.

Note also that `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point I didn't see it. I'll fix and update. Also, I included the `sizeof(char)` so that I don't get confused, I know it is bad form generally. Although now, I only get the last buffer whereas with `sizeof(response)` program execution took longer than it should have but printed out everything.